# What is the path rays in Fabry–Pérot interferometer for calculation it resolution?

Tags: interference, diffraction, dispersion, interferometry

A Fabry-Perot interferometer shown in Figure below essentially consists of two parallel plates of glass whose inner surfaces are polished to a very high degree of flatness, and then coated with a highly reflecting thin film of silver or aluminum or some similarly good reflector.

[image]

An instrument used for resolving spectral lines is rated by its resolving power. It is proportional to the inverse of minimum separation in wavelengths Δλmin
$  R \propto \frac1{\Delta\lambda_{min}}$
that the instrument can resolve.

I don't quite understand how different wavelengths are separated in an interferometer. If, say, white light falls on the interferometer, then there seems to be no reason for dispersion, all rays in the air gap ($n = 1$) will follow the same paths, and will exit the interferometer in the same way. I don't see the reason for the dispersion. How to correctly depict the path of rays for light with close wavelengths?

[image]

Comment: Where did the diagrams come from as I believe that in a number of aspects they can be misleading?

Comment: Typically you move one of the mirrors over the free spectral range. The transmitted spectrum at the resonance is high, and can be very narrow line width. The transmitted light is measured with a photo detector. You can think of it as tunable filter and resolution is determined by the FWHM of the resonance. The resolution is better the more reflective the mirrors are. The free spectral range depends on the distance between the mirrors.  You usually are only measuring the signal within the wavelengths defined by the free spectral range.

Answer (score 1):

*. . . . all rays in the air gap (n=1) will follow the same paths, and will exit the interferometer . . . .*  is a correct statement but misses the essential point that the emerging (parallel) rays are focussed onto a screen ie the emerging waves are made to overlap (superpose).
Looking at the second diagram and starting with the emergent ray on the left, each successive emergent ray has to travel an extra distance which can be shown to be $2d\cos \theta$ where $d$ is the separation of the inner reflecting surfaces and $\theta$ is the angle from the normal of the incident ray labelled $I_0$
If all the emergent rays arrive in phase at the position where they overlap there will be a maximum intensity but is they arrive out of phase there will be a minimum intensity.
The condition for a maximum of intensity (constructive interference) is $2d\cos \theta = m \lambda$ where $m$ is an integer and $\lambda$ is the wavelength of light and so that is how dispersion arises.

*If, say, white light falls on the interferometer,* you will not be able to observe  fringes because the path differences are going to be very large compared to the wavelength of light involved which will mean that the integers $m$ involved will be very large and fringes from slightly differing wavelengths will overlap one another.
Here is a photograph of Newton's rings using white light.

[image]

The formation of Newton's rings has similarities with the Fabry-Perot and $m$ values (ring number) are relatively small.
Note how the fringes become less distinct the further they are away from the centre  due to the overlap of wavelengths.
Now imagine the overlap when $m$ is of the order of tens of thousands as it would be in a Fabry-Perot, there would be so much overlap no distinct fringes would be visible.

White light fringes are observable if $d$ is made comparable to the wavelengths in white light as in effect it is in a Newton's rings arrangement

An essential feature of the Fabry-Perot is that the fringes produces are very narrow/sharp and so a fringes position due to one wavelength can be located accurately and will be distinct from a fringe produced by a slightly differing wavelength - this is why the resolving power is high.

Here is a photograph of the fringes produced by the light from a spectral lamp with a limited number of wavelength emitted using a Fabry-Perot arrangement.

[image]

Notice how much sharper the fringes are.

Comment: I updated second pictures with ray paths, hope it is correct.